# Control computer mouse using a webcam

Tags: mouse, webcam, image-recognition

I am looking for a solution to control my computer mouse just with my hands and a webcam. The goal is to combine it with voice input to let me move more freely in front of my desk.

It should support the usual mouse actions:

- position mouse pointer, left click, right click, middle click, scroll up, scroll down
- optionally: scroll left, scroll right

Comment: If you have a disability and are looking for a mouse alternative, then please note that there are also foot controlled computer mouse solutions available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [DedoMouse](https://achimmihca.github.io/DedoMouse/)

  - Uses hand gestures to control the mouse pointer
  - Meets the requirements: position mouse pointer, left click, right click, middle click, scroll up, scroll down
  - Built using Google [MediaPipe](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/hands) library
  - Modern UI that makes it pretty easy to use
  - Code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/achimmihca/DedoMouse)
  - Requires full hand motion. Thus, not intended for people with disabilities.

    - However, might be useful if you have RSI because of more variety in hand positions.

Comment: There are several answers here.  Please post each as a separate answer, that way each can be voted upon by the community separately.

Comment: welcome **mihca**! awesome apps I never knew I wanted to know about. I second @Chenmunka, splitting the apps to separate answers would better suite the site's culture.

Comment: I split this answer to multiple anwsers

Answer (score 0):

- [eViacam](https://eviacam.crea-si.com/)

  - Uses your head position to position the mouse pointer
  - Code is on [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eviacam/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/cmauri/eviacam)
  - Intended for people with disabilities

Answer (score 0):

- [cameramouse](http://cameramouse.org)

  - Not open source, but free to use
  - Uses your head position to position the mouse pointer and to perform clicks
  - Intended for people with disabilities

Answer (score 0):

- [NPointer](https://www.disabled-world.com/assistivedevices/computer/npointer.php)

  - Not open source and discontinued

Answer (score 0):

- [SmyleMouse](https://smylemouse.com/)

  - Professional and commercial solution to control the computer mouse with your head
  - Intended for people with disabilities

**Controls**

1. Move your head to

   - Move the mouse pointer
2. Smile to

   - Click a mouse, or
   - Make an adaptive switch selection

Answer (score 0):

Besides these, I found some prototypes/unfinished projects, some with academic background:

- [ofnote/gestop](https://github.com/ofnote/gestop)

  - idea: use machine learning to train model with custom gestures and bind them to any input.
  - Cool idea, but more of a prototype I would say.
- [bm371613/gest](https://github.com/bm371613/gest)

  - Pinch gesture to scroll. Nice idea but more of a prototype.
  - The machine learning model seems to be trained manually to detect finger positions and from the description, it seems biased towards the developer.

    - Could maybe benefit from using [Google MediaPipe](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/hands)
- [Mouse_control](https://github.com/nitinkathpalia09/Mouse_control)

  - Academic prototype it seems.
  - Uses colors to detect the finger positions in the image, similar to "Mouse Control using a Web Camera based on Color Detection" by Abhik Banerjee, Abhirup Ghosh, Koustuvmoni Bharadwaj
- [whatifif/handgesture](https://github.com/whatifif/handgesture)

  - Academic prototype with custom trained model. Pretty cool but not a finished product.
- [mouse-control-via-webcam on codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/498193/mouse-control-via-webcam)

  - I was not able to make this work
- [Ashvin-G/Virtual-Mouse](https://github.com/Ashvin-G/Virtual-Mouse)

  - Similar approach to DedoMouse (both using [Google MediaPipe](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/hands)) but less polished
- [albpurpura/HandMouse](https://github.com/albpurpura/HandMouse)

  - Again, similar approach to DedoMouse (uses Google MediaPipe) but less polished and not as much gestures as DedoMouse